# Propagating down the result of groupby aggregations

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following DataFrame

```
                       X         Y
A    B      C                    
bar  one    P   0.630667  1.457555
     three  Q   1.163132 -0.944378
            T   0.423349  0.432508
flux six    P  -1.055297 -0.419939
     three  T   2.064113  0.465885
foo  five   Q   0.271349  0.472808
            S  -0.985560 -0.301500
            P  -0.482336 -0.089823
            R   0.745047 -0.713639
```

I need to identify the value of level `C` within each value of `B` for which `X` has the highest value, and propagate it back to every row.

The result should be:

```
                       X         Y  W
A    B      C                    
bar  one    P   0.630667  1.457555  P
     three  Q   1.163132 -0.944378  Q
            T   0.423349  0.432508  Q
flux six    P  -1.055297 -0.419939  P
     three  T   2.064113  0.465885  T
foo  five   Q   0.271349  0.472808  R
            S  -0.985560 -0.301500  R
            P  -0.482336 -0.089823  R
            R   0.745047 -0.713639  R
```

How can I do that?

So far I have something along the following lines:

```
df.groupby(level=['A', 'B']).agg(lambda x: x.max())
```

but I don't know how to get "propagate" down the result to the original rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you can combine `transform` (which is the "propagate down" part, although I always think of it as broadcasting up) with `idxmax`:

```
>>> df["W"] = df.groupby(level=["A", "B"])["X"].transform(lambda x: x.idxmax()[2])
>>> df
                     X         Y  W
A    B     C                       
bar  one   P  0.630667  1.457555  P
     three Q  1.163132 -0.944378  Q
           T  0.423349  0.432508  Q
flux six   P -1.055297 -0.419939  P
     three T  2.064113  0.465885  T
foo  five  Q  0.271349  0.472808  R
           S -0.985560 -0.301500  R
           P -0.482336 -0.089823  R
           R  0.745047 -0.713639  R

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am particularly interested in a solution that works for **any** lambda/function that I use in aggregation (sorry, the maximum lambda  was just for the sake of an example). Would this work for any lambda?

Comment: Thanks. It did work. I can't believe it was as simple as using `transform` instead of `lambda` !

Answer (score 1):

Want one that is not using `transform`?

```
In [101]:

df2=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=['A', 'B'])['X'].agg(np.argmax).apply(lambda x: x[-1]))
#or pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=['A', 'B'])['X'].agg(lambda x: x.idxmax()[-1]))
df['W']=df2.loc[df.index.droplevel(2)].values
In [102]:

print df
                     X         Y  W
A    B     C                       
bar  one   P  0.630667  1.457555  P
     three Q  1.163132 -0.944378  Q
           T  0.423349  0.432508  Q
flux six   P -1.055297 -0.419939  P
     three T  2.064113  0.465885  T
foo  five  P -0.482336 -0.089823  Q
           Q  0.271349  0.472808  Q
           R -0.745047 -0.713639  Q
           S -0.985560 -0.301500  Q

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

It is easy to get this part, 
    In [115]:

```
print pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=['A', 'B'])['X'].agg(lambda x: x.idxmax()[-1]))
            X
A    B       
bar  one    P
     three  Q
flux six    P
     three  T
foo  five   Q

[5 rows x 1 columns]
```

but it is not as strait forwards to assign it back as `'W'`